2-tap Yule Walker Prediction Filter for DPCM
I came across certain numericals for finding autocorrelation coefficients and prediction gain for a 2-tap Yule Walker Prediction Filter in DPCM. However, I am unable to find any good relevant content for the same anywhere.
Can someone explain -

What is a 2-tap Yule Walker Prediction Filter in DPCM
What are the 2 Yule Walker Equations and how to derive/use them?

This is in context to the specific question:

Consider using a Yule-Walker prediction filter in a DPCM transmitter.
The message m(t) is assumed to be a real WSS process with the
following discrete autocorrelation function: R[k]=2^-|k|

Find, in dB, the processing gain GDP achieved by using a 2-tap Yule-Walker prediction filter.
Find, in dB, the improvement in signal quality achieved by DPCM over the one achieved by a DM transmitter. Assume both transmitters sample
the message m(t) at the same sampling rate.


P.S. - I am not asking for the exact solution of this numerical but the concept behind it.

Hi! Your question is a bit broad. The Yule-Walker equations are really explained in standard DSP literature, already, and we don't know what notational conventions the course you're taking has. So, please tell us much more about what you understood about Y-W equations (and if necessary, just consult wikipedia and explain what you do and do not understand). It's no sense that our answers just repeat the same thing written in literature that you already have access to – you'd still need to understand the same amount of things.
